# How to fasten this parsing loop from textfile

Tags: c#, optimization, text-files

I'm a c# begginer so I might have missed some easy tips.
Here's my question :

I have a loop, reading from a text file some data.
I Have 160 files with 14000 lines of 7 values inside.
i'm interested in getting only some of this line depending of a time correspondance form a existing column in datatable.
If i found a corresping line, I update the line in Datatable.

The actual code take about 6min by file.... It's really too long... 
Any idea to fast up this loop ?
I allready tried to reduce the loop with a while loop...

File sample :
Sample of the file :

Col1        Col2   Col3 Col4       Col5     Col6

15943100    1188    1   2,49       2,28    75,3

15943200    1188    1   2,49       2,28    75,3

15943300    1188    1   2,50       2,28    75,3

15943400    1188    1   2,50       2,28    75,3

Here's the code : (Edited from Aluan Haddad answer but not faster)

```
 foreach (string FileName in fileFastPath)
        {
           var start = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(FileName);

            foreach (var line in allLines.Where(line => line.Contains("Acquisition depuis")))
            {
                DateTimeOffset.TryParse(line.Split('\t')[1], out start);
            }

            double x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

            foreach (var (sp1, sp2, vear, milliseconds) in from line in allLines
                                                           where !line.Contains("Acquisition depuis")
                                                           select line.Split('\t') into values
                                                           where values.Length >= 5
                                                           where double.TryParse(values[3], out x)
                                                           where double.TryParse(values[4], out y)
                                                           where double.TryParse(values[5], out z)
                                                           let milliseconds = double.Parse(values[0])
                                                           where milliseconds % 1000 == 0
                                                           select (x, y, z, milliseconds))
            {
                var updatedStart = start + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds);
                var existingValue = Data
                    .Select($"Time = #{updatedStart: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}#")
                    .FirstOrDefault(existing => existing != null);

                if (existingValue != null)
                {
                    existingValue["SP1 Bar"] = sp1;
                    existingValue["SP2 Bar"] = sp2;
                    existingValue["VEAR_POS %"] = vear;
                }
            }                
        }
```

Comment: You could process the files in parallel and do the DB update in an async fashion. This could all potentially save time. Have you set up some timers to see what is slow? The DB could be slow and need an index?

Comment: May I ask for a little file exemple even 2 line anonimised.

Comment: Quite possibly `Data.Select(...)` is taking up most of these minutes, if I were you I'd measure that using the `Stopwatch` class.

Comment: I'm not working with but a datatable.
I guess Select take most of the time but I don't know how  can I found correspondance in my table in a different way.

Comment: Use the Performance Profiler to see were most of the processing time is spent then react accordingly

Comment: Why do you use two nested loops! your file contains 14000 lines the outer foreach loop and the while loop iterate all lines, so potentially you could get 14000 * 14000 iterations
I didn't understand exactly what you want to achieve, maybe you only need one iteration.

Comment: i use the while to reduce the for loop once i achieve a certain condition. this is working fine ! But not very efficient, not enough !

Comment: @Siraf is right I think. You may not need that while loop in there. You're potentially doing 14,000 x (14,000 - 4) iterations per file. But without understanding why you do a second traversal with the while loop if there is no matching text, it's hard to suggest a fix

Comment: you r looking for a value in a line, if you find it in the line then you extract it, if you don't find it you go to the next line, so basically you need to processing time that is equivalent to iterating 14000 lines in a text file, this is done in fraction of a second, just test it yourself, comment the body of your foreach loop and run it you will see that it iterates very very fast

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning up your code so you can see the forest for the trees. As you do so, there are many optimizations that reveal themselves thanks to clearer program structure.

```
foreach (var fileName in fileFastPath)
{
    var start = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

    foreach (var line in allLines.Where(line => line.Contains("Acquisition depuis")))
    {
        DateTimeOffset.TryParse(line.Split('\t')[1], out start);
    }

    double x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

    var lineValues = from line in allLines
                     where !line.Contains("Acquisition depuis")
                     select line.Split('\t') into values
                     where double.TryParse(values[3], out x)
                     where double.TryParse(values[4], out y)
                     where double.TryParse(values[5], out z)
                     let milliseconds = double.Parse(values[0])
                     select (x, y, z, milliseconds);

    foreach (var (sp1, sp2, vear, milliseconds) in lineValues)
    {
        var updatedStart = start + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds);
        var existingValue = Data
            .Select($"Time = #{updatedStart: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}#")
            .FirstOrDefault(existing => existing != null);

        if (existingValue != null)
        {
            existingValue["SP1 Bar"] = sp1;
            existingValue["SP2 Bar"] = sp2;
            existingValue["VEAR_POS %"] = vear;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't run your code, there is an error near :

foreach (var (sp1, sp2, vear, milliseconds) in from line in allLines

Comment: You need the latest version of C# (7.2)

Comment: Any idea why I can't use later than 6.0 ?

Comment: Because tuples were introduced in 7.0. You actually don't need 7.2 just 7.0. Install Visual Studio 2017 and you will be fine. Its been out for like 6 months now. Also, if you have LINQPad 5+, you can use that.

Comment: ok Thanks, I didn't know about this ...

i have still an error with "x" in the last select  statement and I'm lost with your querry :D

Erreur CS8179 the predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`4' is not defined or imported

Comment: You need to install the package if you hover and select the quickfix (`ctrl+.`) it will do it for you. Or upgrade project to .NET 4.7 +

Comment: Now i have a problem for debug... OMG ! I found out I might have to remove 2015 version to let2017 works...

Comment: They can side by side install. Several colleagues and I worked that way for a long time.

Comment: When I try to run debug session I have an error about debugging setup installation (vs2017 is freshed installed). I was looking on forum and people saying there might have a conflict beetwen installation. Anyway I don't have  other idea about how to solve this ...
I was using VS express2015.

Comment: So I did try your solution and I made it working finally !
This isn't more efficient, I need 450-500 ms beetwen each relevant values !
There are 112605 relevant values to add wich mean around 15 hours to run !
Thanks you for the proposition anyway, code looks sexier ;)

Comment: @arnaud you can chain `.AsParallel()` to the LINQ expressions and get multi core execution. That is a hidden perf benefit of the declarative style. Try it out. Glad you think it's sexy ;)